# Cloud like texture forming

Tags: texturing, materials

I have created a bottle with liquid in it and I am getting very strange effect to it. Like the glass has been smeared with oil or something.

I cant for the life of me work out what it is. I am after a clean clear glass and liquid.
I have been through all the objects, deleted them, changed values but can seem to find the problem.

[image]

I would gladly upload the file however it is quite large, is there a way t upload the file as I am not sure this can be answered without seeing the file, as I am not sure where the problem is coming from

Comment: Hi :). Looks a lot like denoising artifacts, are you using a denoiser? Increased samples should help if that's the case.

Comment: I am not using any denoiser. The glass is a very basic glass material. But, it seems upping the samples did something. I did have it at 100, and ramped it up to 400. Im a bit of a newbie to Blender and so a little unsure of how many samples I should be using ;) Ill pump it up some more and see what happens Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hey :). Denoiser might be active by default, check your render settings. Fyi around 1000 samples is a good ballpark, official Blender Movies are rendered with minimum 2000 samples per frame.

Comment: ha ha blimey, my 100 samples was slightly on the low side then. Denoiser has been checked, should it be unchecked?

Comment: Hi :). Denoiser works great, most people use it, just with low samples you get those smudges. There's simply no way around higher render samples ;)

Comment: Ah ha got ya, thanks so much for all the help. Slowly getting there. ALl the best and have a great christmas

Comment: You're doing great, welcome to Blender. all the best to you too ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.